# For repeated data, why we don't use just OLS with sandwich SEs but rather GLS or mixed models?

Tags: least-squares, repeated-measures, panel-data, generalized-least-squares, robust-standard-error

If I have repeated observations and want to summarize the means at each time point, the OLS will give me the true, raw means, while the GLS will give me means dependent on the selected covariance structure.

Why not just use the OLS with sandwich SEs reflecting the within-subject dependency, having the estimates of means unchanged? Using the GLS results in reporting different mean, if the covariance isn't just "independence".

Comment: I am not sure if this applies in the context of repeated observations, but the general reason for preferring GLS to OLS with robust SEs is that we get more accurate point estimates. That sounds appealing enough for me.